# can I set the AppUserModelID of an arbitrary process launched through a jumplist?

Tags: c++, windows-7, taskbar, jump-list

I have a simple console application written in C++ that acts as a stub for launching another application through it's jumplist. Purpose is to add jumplist abilities to applications that do not support this. Call it stub.exe. When running stub.exe it creates a custom jumplist using these steps (taken right form the MS samples):

```
create an ICustomDestinationList
ICustomDestinationList::BeginList()
create an IObjectCollection
for_each item_to_add
  create an IShellLink, set its path/arguments/title/icon
  add IShellLink to the IObjectCollection
get the IObjectArray interface from the IObjectCollection
call ICustomDestinationList::AddUserTasks( IObjectArray interface )
ICustomDestinationList::CommitList()
```

When pinning stub.exe to the taskbar and right-clicking it, the jumpilst appears and it contains all IShellLinks added. When clicking an item, it will launch the corresponding process.

Now I'd like a process launched through this jumplist have it's window(s) grouped under stub.exe's taskbar icon, instead of having it's own group. They key to get this working seems to be the AppUsermodelID. This is what I tried so far:

- just for testing, create a couple of shortcuts and set the id through IPropertyStore->SetValue( PKEY_AppUserModel_ID, "id" ). Indeed, when launching these shortcuts, they will all group under the same taskbar icon.
- since the shortcuts do what I want, I tried adding shortcuts to stub.exe's jumplist: no effect. The shortcuts don't even show up in the jumplist (maybe one cannot have a shortcut to a shortcut?), yet all methods return S_OK
- setting the PKEY_AppUserModel_ID on each of the IShellLinks that get added to the jumplist: no effect
- calling ICustomDestinationList->SetAppID(): no effect
- instead of using SubTasks, tried with SHAddToRecentDocs: no effect. The recent doc list does not show up. But now things get messy. After setting the AppUserModelID on the shortcut that is responsible for the pinned taskbar item (the one in %APPDATA%/Roaming/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/Quick Launch/User Pinned/TaskBar), the jumplist changed: it does not show the 'Tasks' item anymore, but does show 'Recent' and the items I added using SHAddToRecentDocs. Now when clicking them I get a dialog box with a title that starts with 'd:\desktop' followed by Chinese characters. Hovering the items in the jumplist also shows Chinese characters instead of the descirption I set.

Questions:

1. What's with the Chinese characters in the jumplist?
2. How come setting the app id on the taskbar shortcut toggles between 'Tasks' and 'Recent' sections, why are they not both there?
3. What would be the way, if even possible, to achive what I actually want: a custom jump list of which the items launched will group under it's taskbar icon? (note that the processes I plan to laucnh their do not have their app id set currently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not much reactions here ;]

In the meantime I managed to solve the main problem myself; it's not quite a straightforward solution but it fullfills the requirements: a program runs in the backround and installs a CBT hook. Each time an application creates a window (HookProc code = HCBT_CREATEWND), the hook checks the application's path against a map containing paths and desired application ids. If a match is found, the application id of the HWND is set. Since this occurs before the window is actually shown and is combined with the custom task list, from a user's point of view the application behaves just like one that does support a recent/pinned document list.

Comment: Hi there @stijin I am also going to be running into this situation. I was going to use `SHGetPropertyStore` to set window app user ids, but i dont know how to do it before the window shows, will this break the jump list?

Comment: @Noitidart sorry, no idea and it has been ages I used this software.. Just try and see I would say. Or look for some open source lib for dealing with jump lists maybe?

Comment: Thanks @stijn im doing in non-c to c (js-ctypes) so its tricky to tell if it doesnt work. I was just wondeirng was it possible to set properties of other process once you got `IPropertyStore` of it via `SHGetPropertyStoreFromWindow`?

Comment: Yesss thank you @stijn!! I needed that ability real bad so now it makes it easy to figure out if somethiing is not working its my code somewhere. Thanks very much!!

Comment: you were right no problem setting windows of other process id's, absolutely excellent thank you! :)